# Find amount of invertible matrices of size $3 \times 3$ over residue field modulo 5

Tags: matrices, field-theory

Find amount of invertible matrices of size $3 \times 3$ over residue field modulo 5. I will just add that this task is slightly ahead of my knowledge of field theory. So any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The task should be in the body, not just in the title. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Never mind, I did it myself. Anyway, do you have any thoughts about the answers that have been posted?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for edit and answer. Actually 'slightly ahead' was an euphemism, and I found myself unable to solve it even with your suggestions and I already passed my test without completing this task.
But since you guys put an effort in writing suggestions, it feels like I have to solve it anyway.

Comment: OK, let's go through my answer. "The top row has to be a nonzero vector". Do you see why this is true? Can you compute the number of nonzero vectors?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. Actually, I have reread Wiki articles about that dozen times at least. They are hard to get due to lack of examples.
Residue field - some kind of factorgroup, with maximal ideal. Maximal ideal - is the conception, which I totally don't understand.

Comment: Ah, I see more clearly what the difficulty is. "Residue field modulo 5" just means working in the integers, modulo 5. Have you never done congruences, or what's called modular arithmetic, or sometimes called "clock arithmetic"? We're working in an arithmetic where the only numbers are $0,1,2,3,4$, and where the result of each arithmetical operation is replaced by the remainder on dividing by 5. So, for example, $3\times4=2$, because 2 is the remainder on dividing 12 by 5. Does that help?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yep, thank you. I had a course where we did some of ring theory and modular arithmetics too. But it was English course while this task was originally given at Russian, so I got lost in translation:) Now I'm ready to put hands on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top row has to be a nonzero vector.

The 2nd row has to not be a scalar multiple of the top row.

The bottom row has to not be a linear combination of the other two rows.

You should be able to count these things, and combine them appropriately.

Comment: Ok, we are interested in all nonsingular matrices. So rows are supposed to be linearly independent.
I feel that all possible values of the first row could be found by Stanley's formula. $((\frac {n+k-1}{k}))= | where: n=5; k=3 | =(\frac 7 3) = \frac {7!}{3!4!} = 35$ Then, minus zero vector, we have 34 total. Though, I got difficulty with counting other rows.

Comment: I don't know why you think that formula applies. The top row is $(x\ y\ z)$. $x$ can be any of the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4; so can $y$; so can $z$; but we can't allow all three of them to be zero. So, how many possibilities for the top row?

Comment: I suppose, $5^3-1$

Comment: Yes! Now, the second row also has to be $(x\ y\ z)$ but it can't be a scalar multiple of the first row. "Scalar multiple" just means a number times the 1st row, and remember we only have 5 numbers. So, how many possibilities for the second row?

Comment: Hm, $(5^3-1)-4$, since 1,2,3,4 are suitable scalars for that.

Comment: Good, though simpler to just write $5^3-5$, as multiplication by 0 also gives a scalar multiple. Now, you know what a linear combination is? Given two vectors $v$ and $w$, can you work out how many linear combinations there are of $v$ and $w$? And so how many vectors there are that aren't linear combinations of $v$ and $w$?

Comment: We have $5^2$ linear combinations of v and w, hence final answer is $(5^3-1)(5^3-5)(5^3-5^2)$.
Thank you so much for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take a vector space $\;V\;$ over $\;\Bbb F_5\;$ s.t. $\;\dim V=3\;$. How many basis (ordered ones, of course) does $\;V\;$ have?

For exaple, to make calculations simpler you could take the elementary group $\;\Bbb F_5\times\Bbb F_5\times\Bbb F_5\;$ with the obvious scalar product...

Comment: Yep. I did find multiple mentions over the web, that these problems are connected. Actually I found out that it's a task from the classic algebra book, so I even have right answer to check with now, $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\dots(q^n-q^{n-1})$.

But I don't see how problem stated in task could be reduced to amount-of-basises problem, and I don't see the way to count all possible basises. I appreciate your effort and would be grateful if you provide some further pointers.

Comment: @wf34, over a field $\;F\;$: a square matrix of order $\;n\;$ is invertible iff its $\;n\;$ rows, taken as vectors of $\;F^n\;$, are linearly independent, iff these vectors are a basis of $\;F^n\;$ over $\;F\;$. Thus, to count *invertible matrices* of order $\;n\;$ is **exactly** the same as to count (ordered, of course) basis of $\;F^n\;$ . In our case, with $\;F=\Bbb F_5\;$: in how many ways can we choose the first vectors (row) for our $\;3\times3\;$ matrix? Well, since $\;|F^3|=5^3\;$, we have $\;5^3-1\;$ choices: **any** vector except the zero one, and etc.